# What is this referring to?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

From standard Rails installation, in app/assets/javascripts/cable.js:

```
// Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
// You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the
// `rails generate channel` command.
//
// = require action_cable
// = require_self
// = require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();
}).call(this);
```

M unclear as to what `this` is referring to. Also, I get a warning about it being a top-level `this`

Is there a straightforward way to improve this?

Comment: `this` is the global context - and the function that gets created there is called with that context.  Read [more in  the JS MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: you can always console.log(this) to see what it is referring to

Comment: Yeah, I got that from JS MDN @Adelin I was hoping for a Rails perspective. I am just learning Rails, and I can't just run this as straight JS code to just check ```this```. Maybe it references something from ActionCable? Hopefully, a Rails person can clarify! ;)

Comment: @VisWebsoft Rails is rails, JS is JS. You can't look at JS from Rails perspective. That piece of code checks if `App` exists in the global context and, if it doesn't, it gets initialized as an empty object and then whatever `createCustomer` returns is stored in the `App` object. This will be true if the code was server by java, python, ruby - you name it.

Comment: Actually, that does make sense, mostly. But, what you explained is all about what is inside function. How can we tell, what ```this``` is that the fxn. is calling after the operations you described are done? In this way, maybe another person can reference something from Rails or ActionCable...

Comment: This is a relatively small thing, so I guess the answer will just become clearer as I progress on my Rails (and JS) studies.